# Loop not display all lines when adding a sum function

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, sum

I am reading an external txt file and displaying all the lines which has field 6 as Y. I then need to count these lines. However, when I add the sum function it will only print 1 of the lines, if I remove this sum function all the lines display as expected. I am presuming its something to do with the for loop but can't seem figure out how to get all lines to display and keep my sum. Can anyone help me spot where this is going wrong?

```
noLines = 0

fileOpen = open ("file.txt","r")
print ("Name: " + "\tDate: " + "\tAge: " + "\tColour: " + "\tPet")

for line in fileOpen:
    line = line[:-1]
    field = line.split(',')

    if field[6] == "Y":
        print()
        print (field[0] +"\t\t" + field[1] + "\t" + field[2] + "\t\t" + field[3] + "\t\t" + field[4])

        noLines = sum(1 for line in fileOpen)

print ()
print(noLines)
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces before or after "Y"? I suggest stripping them off just in case: `if field[6].strip() == "Y":...` You also reset the line count in each loop iteration. This is probably _not_ what you want.

Comment: @Sarah: You should not change the question the way it makes existing answers invalid. Please do not edit the code as these questions also act as a reference for future users (not just you). Please comment on my answer the issue and I will try to help you resolve the issue (as per best of my knowledge)

Comment: You should edit the code to make you question clean and clear. But changing the context of the question is the exploitation of SO's edit feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sum` incorrectly. In order to achieve the desired result, you may replace your current code with `sum` as:

```
noLines = sum(1 for l in open("file.txt","r") if l[:-1].split(',')[6]=='Y')
```

---

*Issue with current code:* Because `fileOpen` is a generator. You are exhausting it completely within `sum` and hence your next `for` iteration is not happening. Instead of using sum, you may initialize `noLines` before the `for` loop as:

```
noLines = 0

for line in fileOpen:
     # your stuff ...
```

And instead of `sum`, do:

```
noLines += 1
# instead of: noLines = sum(1 for line in fileOpen)
```

Comment: Hi I have done this. See my edited code in my original post. Nothing now prints though for count of the lines?

Comment: @SarahProctoer Did you again opened the file using `fileOpen = open ("file.txt","r")`?

Comment: @SarahProctoer Also, you should define `noLines = 0` before `for` loop. Check in the answer (edited to make it clear)

Comment: Ok is it now all displaying. But the counting of the lines is wrong, it is just giving me 1 line as the count when it should be 60+.

Comment: check my last comment

Comment: Ok sorted that - defined before the for loop. It is giving me count which is 1 too many according to my calculations.

Comment: computers are never wrong, your calculation might be. The issue  might be in your `l[:-1].split(',')[6]=='Y'` logic. print the values and try to debug what is wrong